# How to create custom Google Docs Form with a custom theme?

Tags: google-drive

Google Docs Form offer a bunch of themes but I need to create custom one. I need my banner at the top of form- questionnaire. How can I do that?

Comment: James Doyle has a nice explanation for how to do this at http://ohdoylerules.com/web/custom-google-forms If you know your way around html, it's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

On September 2, 2014 Google announced custom themes. See [Your forms, your way](http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2014/09/custom-forms-themes.html) post on Google Drive blog.

The steps from the related help article [Add a theme to a form - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/145737?hl=en) are the following:

> **Create a custom theme**
>   If you want even more control over how your form looks, you can create your own custom theme.
>
> 1. Open the form.
> 2. Click Change theme in the toolbar.
> 3. Find one of the existing templates in the panel on the right to use
>      as a starting point and click Customize under the name of that
>      template.
> 4. Select a section of the form in the panel on the right to begin
>      editing that section. Some of the options you can customize include:
>
>    - Adding custom images to the header and the page background
>    - Choosing font, font size, font color, and paragraph alignment for the    form text
>    - Choosing a color for the form and page backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can.
Best option is to create a Google Site and embed your plain form in it.